# How start new activity after successful Facebook login?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login

I am making Facebook login. In my main XML I have just Facebook login button.

I want to start new page after successful Facebook login but after successful Facebook login it does not show my new XML page (welcome XML layout). Instead it shows empty white page.

How can I fix this?

[GitHub link](https://github.com/berkkarabacak/Scarce)

My fragment:

```
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private CallbackManager callbackManager;
        private FacebookCallback<LoginResult>callback=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                //Is there problem here?
                AccessToken accessToken=loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile=Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), com.berkkarabacak.scarce.Profile.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //Is there problem here?


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            }
        };


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            callbackManager=CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        }

        @Override


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            LoginButton loginButton=(LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
            loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
            loginButton.setFragment(this);
            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,callback);
            return rootView;
            }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `YourActivity.this` instead of `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: I see you are trying to start `Profile.class` but I went to your github link but didn't see that file. Can you post the code for that class?

Comment: @Zamereon Github has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this;

```
        Fragment fragment = new sendFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Even though the answer might correctly adress the issue in question, consider adding a brief explanation of how you solved the problem for completness

Answer (score 1):

Use the activity context

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), com.berkkarabacak.scarce.Profile.class);
```

Comment: Nope,it does not work.Still shows empty white screen after login